# Karma - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG4FH60fhUE and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html to write simple unit test cases in Angular 2 and verify the setup of Karma. I get this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import --- compute.spec.ts:2 .The syntax is very simple and looks similar to the tutorial. But I dont know why I am getting this error. These are the versions used

```
 //package.json
    "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.10",
    "@types/c3": "^0.4.39",
    "angular-hammer": "^2.2.0",
    "angular2-mqtt": "^1.7.1",
    "c3": "^0.4.11",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "^3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.10",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "@types/c3": "^0.4.39",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "c3": "^0.4.11",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.2",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.2.2"
  }

My project structure 

    myproject
     -src
       -app
         -01-fundamentals
           -compute.ts
           -compute.spec.ts   
     -karma.conf.js

    //compute.spec.ts

    import {compute} from './compute';
    describe('compute',() => {

        it('should return 0 if input is negative', () => {
      const result= compute(-1);
      expect(result).toBe(0);
    })
    })

    //karma.conf.js
    module.exports = function(config) {
      config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: ["src/app/**/*.spec.ts"
        ],
        exclude: [
        ],
        preprocessors: {
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity,
        plugins: [ 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-chrome-launcher'],
        mime: {
          'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
        },
      })
    }
```

Comment: I figured out that we need to use some preprocessor. I tried with **karma- typescript**  preprocessor. After installing this I get different error that ` you need adapter to run karma start method` this is crazy. Trying to solve one issue and other one pops up !!

Comment: Welcome to the world of modern web development... I'm facing the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Run your test with --sourcemaps=false and you will get the right error messages.

```
ng test --sm=false
```